Create a new line for comma separated values in pandas column - I dont want to add new rows, I want to have same rows in output
I have a dataframe like this,
df
col1    col2
 1       'abc,pqr'
 2       'ghv'
 3       'mrr, jig'

Now I want to create a new line for each comma separated values in col2, so the output would look like,
col1    col2
 1       'abc
          pqr'
 2       'ghv'
 3       'mrr
          jig'

looking for some easy solutions in pandas

out = df.assign(col2=lambda x: x['col2'].str.split(',')).explode('col2')

this is not what I want, I want keep same number of rows but explode increases the number of rows

Then you want to replace , by \n? df['col2'] = df['col2'].str.replace(',', '\n'). Note that there is no straightforward way to display this (as text) with a line jump without creating new rows. If you're in a notebook, you can display a line jump in HTML with display(HTML(df.to_html().replace(',', '<br>'))).

To create an artificial display of newlines by creating new rows: print(df.assign(col2=lambda x: x['col2'].str.split(',')).explode('col2').assign(col1=lambda x: x['col1'].mask(x['col1'].duplicated(), '')).to_string(index=False))
